# Postman hangs and seems to not call route

Tags: node.js, postman

I am making a server for an Android app that I am making. When I try to send a request through Postman it just sits on this screen (host is http://localhost:4000):
[image: Postman screen]

Here is my app.js code

```
const app = express()
const cors = require('cors')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
require('dotenv').config()
const source = process.env.USER_CONNECTION
const connection = mongoose.connection
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000
const userRoutes = require('./controllers/user.controller')
const infoRoutes = require('./controllers/info')

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json)
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Successfully served on port: ${port}.`)
})
app.use('/user', userRoutes)
app.use('/info', infoRoutes)

mongoose.connect(source, {
   useNewUrlParser: true,
   useUnifiedTopology: true
})

connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log("DB connected");
})
```

This works and gives me both log statements. Here is my controller file:

```
const router = require('express').Router()
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const generation1 = require('../generation1.json')

router.route('/insertPokemon').post((req, res) => {
    console.log(req)
    const conn = mongoose.createConnection(process.env.POKEMON_CONNECTION, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    })
    conn.once('open', () => {
        console.log("Pokemon DB connected")
    })
    const model = conn.model('Pokemon', pokemon, req.body.generation)

    let pokemonIds = []
    if (req.body.generation === 'generation1') {
        for (i = 0; i < generation1.pokemon.length; i++) {
            console.log(generation1.pokemon[i].name)
            let newPokemon = new model(generation1.pokemon[i])
            newPokemon.save()
                .then(pokemon => {
                    console.log(pokemon.name + ": " + pokemon._id)
                    pokemonIds.push(pokemon._id)
                })
        }
        if (pokemonIds.length === generation1.pokemon.length) {
            console.log('All pokemon entered from generation')
            conn.close()
            res.json({ 'done' : 'all pokemon entered from generation'})
        }
    }
    res.json({'error': 'there is an error'})
})

module.exports = router
```

This does not give me any of the log statements, nor does it return any response. I have been working on this for several days with to no avail. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It should be `app.use(express.json())`

Comment: @Phil Thank you! That worked, but what confuses me is that I use it the same way in a different server for another app and it works perfectly fine.